# can jQuery return the full result of a .wrap() instead of just the original $element?

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a `.wrap()` like so (simplified for readability):

```
$p = $('<em>​sdf​</em>​');
$f = $('<span><p></p></span>');

$r = $p.wrap($f);
```

Now I'm trying to access the resultant `<span><p><em>sdf</em></p></span>` as it's own jQuery object. But `$r` returns the same thing as `$p`. Apparently that's how .`wrap()` works: it returns the wrapped element but nothing else.

How do I get at the full enchilada? Since this is part of a more complex function I cannot make assumptions about the depth of my wrapper tree. Could be 2 elements or 6.

Comment: +1 I found this confusing too. Mmm, enchilada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious answer is:

```
$r = $p.wrap($f).parent();
```

Incidentally, you're working on a faulty assumption: a `p` cannot contain another `p` element. Ever. The DOM, once constructed, will move the inner `p` element out of the intended 'parent' element.

If you're constructing something of arbitrary depth, and want to identify the top-most element, then you could, of course, use:

```
$r = $p.wrap($f).parents().last();
```

Though this assumes that the elements being wrapped aren't present in the DOM at this point, but if they *are* then you can use a selector with `parents()` to limit the potential results:

```
$r = $p.wrap($f).parents('parentClassName').last();
```

You could, of course, always write a simple jQuery plugin, such as:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.altWrap = function (node) {
        var topmost = node[0];
        this.wrap(node);
        return topmost;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Which allows for the following to (seemingly) work under the constraints I *think* you're under:

```
$p = $('<em>​sdf​</em>​');
$f = $('<div><div><span><p></p></span></div></div>');

$r = $p.altWrap($f);

console.log($p,$f,$r);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VVf8q/).

Updated the plugin solution with some (necessary) sanity-checking:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.altWrap = function (node) {
        var topmost, _tmp;
        if (node && node.length) {
            _tmp = node[0];
            while (_tmp.firstChild && _tmp.firstChild.nodeType == 1) {
                _tmp = _tmp.firstChild;
            }
            $(_tmp).append(this);
            topmost = node[0];
        }
        else {
            topmost = this;
        }
        return topmost;
    };
})(jQuery);

$p = $('<em>​sdf​</em>​');
$p2 = $('<em>some text</em>');
$f = $('<div><div><span><p></p></span></div></div>');

console.log($p2.altWrap($f));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VVf8q/3/).

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).
- [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Comment: I guess I have to start disclaiming my questions and clarify that I simplify my code for easier consumption. This is part of a generic function, and I have different numbers of elements, so accessing it with `.parent()` is not going to be of use if I have a tree `n` nodes deep

Comment: Hence the later developments in the answer. Unfortunately, without knowing the constraints under which you're working it's very hard to offer a complete (or guaranteed) answer.

Comment: yea. I'm trusting that using other jQuery functions are the only way. I had hoped there is something akin to how `.append()` differs from `.appendTo()` where they each essentially do the same thing but return different objects as their result.

Comment: I've added a possible plugin that's basically an adapted form of `wrap()`, which *might* solve your problem a little more accurately.

Comment: I tried your updated plugin solution and it doesn't work when you pass a parameter to the altWrap(). For example `$p2.altWrap($f)` simply returns the value for `$f`.

Comment: @tim: thanks for the feedback; I'm amazed that I hadn't realised that until you pointed it out (in my defence, it was late and, clearly, I wasn't paying attention). That said, I *believe* the corrected plugin (the previous version being removed) should work now (though I do think it could be optimised a little). Sorry for my silliness! X(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `wrap` returns the object itself again to provide function chaining like `$p.wrap(...).animate(...).remove();` and so on.

Since you wrap your `$p` into an `p` into an `span` you can get the "full enchilada" via `$r = $p.wrap($f).parent().parent();`

Comment: thanks. I am really not very good at asking proper questions I realize. Sorry. I edited the question for clarification.